# What does the red line on the turbine tower mean?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

Some missions in Splatoon 3 Side Order have a turbine tower you need to continually attack and fill with ink to make it move. There is a red line on the tower's container, similar to the line on an inkling's ink tank that indicates how much ink you need to use a subweapon.

What does the red line on a turbine tower indicate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like a threshold, you need to fill the tank until that red line (as suggested by the "loading" sound you hear), then the rest of the tank will fill automatically, and also the sound emitted in this phase is different.

Once reached the red line:
[image]

the ink level will rise a lot faster:
[image]